# Haskell Error: Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding

Tags: haskell

So this is my code

```
seconds :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
seconds (d,mm) (h,m,s)
  | d > 31 = 0
  | d < 1 = 0
  | mm > 12 = -1
  | mm < 1 = -1
  | h > 24 = -1
  | h < 0 = -1
  | m > 59 = -1
  | m < 0 = -1
  | s > 59 = -1
  | s < 0 = -1
  | otherwise = ((ceiling(div (mm-1) 2) * 31 + floor(div mm-1 2) * 30)-2 + (d-1))*86400 + (h-1)*3600 + m * 60 + s
```

and the error says:

```
ERROR file:seconds.hs:9 - Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
 *** Expression    : seconds
 *** Type          : (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
 *** Given context : ()
 *** Constraints   : (Num a, Num (a -> Int -> Int))
```

Any help?

Comment: `ceiling` can not be applied, since that works on a `RealFrac` type, but it would be useless anyway, since `div` truncates towards zero.

Comment: Indeed, but that's not the only problem with the arithmetic expression. If nothing else, `div mm-1 2` is missing some parentheses. Try splitting up your large, complicated expression by defining some helper functions for sub-parts of it so that it's easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would probably help if you would first of all *simplify* your expression. Right now it is very complicated.

The core reason why it does not work is because expressions like:

```
 div mm  -  1 2
```

are parsed as:

```
(div mm) - (1 2)
```

so that means that `div mm` is supposed to be an number (because of the use of the `(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` function), and `1` is supposed to be a function here, since you apply it to `2`.

You should write:

```
div (mm-1) 2
```

instead:

```
seconds :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
seconds (d,mm) (h,m,s) 
    | d > 31 = 0
    | d < 1 = 0
    | mm > 12 = -1
    | mm < 1 = -1
    | h > 24 = -1
    | h < 0 = -1
    | m > 59 = -1
    | m < 0 = -1
    | s > 59 = -1
    | s < 0 = -1
    | otherwise = ((div (mm-1) 2) * 31 + (div (mm-1) 2)*30 - 2 + (d-1))*86400 + (h-1) * 3600 + m * 60 + s
```

You furthermore can not use [**`ceiling :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:ceiling) or [**`floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor), since as the type signature says, these work on `RealFrac` types, and an `Int` is not a `RealFrac`. This makes sense, since `div (mm-1) 2` will return an `Int` here. What would a `ceiling` or `floor` do on an `Int`?

There are furthermore some odd things in this function. For example `(h-1)`, whereas hours start at `0` (given the first guards perform bound checks), etc. February normally has 28 or 29 days (if it is a leap year), and it looks like this is not taken into account. The function `(div mm 2) * 31 + (div (mm-1) 2)*30` is capable of calculating the number of days for the first half of the year if February had 30 days. But even then August for example has 31 days, so then the repetition of 31, 30, 31, 30, … is lost.

I think however you make things overcomplicated here. It might be better to work with small reusable functions. For example:

```
secondsOfDay :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
secondsOfDay h m s = 3600 * h + 60 * m + s

daysOffset :: Int -> Int
daysOffset 1 = 0
daysOffset 2 = 31
daysOffset 3 = 60
daysOffset 4 = 91
daysOffset 5 = 121
daysOffset 6 = 152
daysOffset 7 = 182
daysOffset 8 = 213
daysOffset 9 = 244
daysOffset 10 = 274
daysOffset 11 = 305
daysOffset 12 = 335
```

Then we can define a function like:

```
seconds :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
seconds (d,mm) (h,m,s) 
    | d > 31 || d < 1 || mm > 12 || mm < 1 = -1
    | h > 24 || h < 0 || m > 59 || m < 0 || s > 59 || s < 0 = -1
    | otherwise = (d + daysOffset mm) * 86400 + secondsOfDay h m s
```

This makes the assumption that we do not calculate the number of seconds for a leap year. Furthermore in reality the calendar has often been adjusted. For example the [*Gregorian calendar* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) was introduced in 1582, which for example changing the leap year rules. Furthermore, [*leap seconds* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_secondhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are often introducec to correct irregluarities of earth rotation. So the above function is not an accurate way to calculate the *exact* number of seconds.